# filter dropDown lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a a inputselect dropdown list which is filling up with text values in init method
Can I somehow filter values depending on key that have been pressed and rerender dropdown?
now I have the following code

```
 <ui:inputSelect aura:id="selectObj" class="slds-select c-select" label="" keyup="{!c.keyUpHandler}" change="{!c.createCriterias}" />
```

**helper**

```
  keyUpHandler: function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('keyPressedEvent>>>>>>>>',event);
    },
```

At this point event only triggered on closed dropdown
When it is expanded  event dosn't fire when I'm pressing any button